# jquery animate on a blackberry

Tags: jquery, blackberry, mobile, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a simple form with a popup message which works on a blackberry?

I need the page to scroll back to the top of the page when the link to the popup is clicked, but the following code doesn't seem to work on a Blackberry...

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
```

Is there an alternative to this which will work across all devices??

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work too well"* Explain. Not every reader is owning a Blackberry.

Comment: Which OS version? Because os 5 and older don't support transition nor HTML5 stuff and even some HTML 4 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could just try animating the body, or html instead of both?

Michael B brings up a good point: which blackberry version is it? if version > 5, it should be using webkit, and it should render (similarly) to iPhone.  I've had some small bugs, but no complete failures since they switched.